# Wait when variable change status in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How I can run some code when my variable change.

for exaple:
**$store.state.AppStatus** have status "busy" when vue component loaded then he change to "ready"

so i need run boostrap function on tab after  $store.state.AppStatus change to "ready"

Now i use setTimeout couse its work but its not perfect...

My code mounted hook:

```
  mounted() {
    
    if (window.location.hash) {
      console.log(this.$store.state.AppStatus)
       setTimeout(() => {
            $(`a[href="${window.location.hash}"]`).tab('show')
          }, 1000);
      
    }  
  },
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should be using an AppStatus variable for this at all. Vue has lifecycle hooks, so depending on what you're defining as 'ready', the lifecycle hook can be used to call your function at a specific point in the lifecycle. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram. If there is a reason you need 'AppStatus', then the lifecycle hook can update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Vue Watcher - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

> While computed properties are more appropriate in most cases, there are times when a custom watcher is necessary. That’s why Vue provides a more generic way to react to data changes through the watch option. This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data.

```js
watch: {
  '$store.state.AppStatus': function() {
    $(`a[href="${window.location.hash}"]`).tab('show')
  }
}
```

Comment: its work but i add setTimeout 100 couse it was maybe to fast for tab :)